# How do we replace the token <front> in a custom module?

Tags: 8, tokens

I am using the following in my custom module but the token is not being replaced. Is this a namespace issue?

```
$token_service = \Drupal::token();
$post_login = $token_service->replace('<front>');
```

Comment: AFAIK `<front>` is not a token, but  some kind of magic route.

Comment: Have you tried `[site:url]`?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, `<front>` is a route, not a token, so you can't use the token API to work with it.

You can resolve it using the [Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x) class:

```
$path = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString();

// $path is equal to '/'
```

But I'm not sure how useful that will be. Perhaps you want to get the front page that's set in config instead:

```
$path = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('page.front');
```